# concatenate or extend list of dictionaries overwriting to last list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, concatenation

my for loop below pulls a list of dictionaries in each iteration. Im trying to extend final_list with all the lists I get in each iteration. But at the end when I print final_list it is just giving me the list from the last iteration. In other words its almost like all the previous lists are being overwritten. Tried everything but nothing works. Can someone point me what might be wrong with my code?

```
for i in range (1,21):
    results_list = []
    final_list = []
    url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XX&primary_release_date.gte=2000-01-01&with_genres=35&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=" + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url, timeout = 10)
    #each page is a dictionary. we get only "results" which is a list.
    #so each iteration of the loop gives us a list to work with
    results_list = response.json()['results']
    final_list.extend(results_list)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Failed to get data:', response.status_code)
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Hi dheeraj.  I [edit]ed your question so that the code stands out properly.  (I did that by putting 4 spaces in front of each line of code.)  I recommend you look closely at where you create `results_list`, as it's likely where not where you wanted to create it.

Comment: try putting `final_list = []` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have results_list twice in your code, once as an empty list which is fine, and the second time as an object. You are not updating your list by:

```
results_list = response.json()['results']
```

You are saving this as an object which is overwriting your empty list. Instead, store each value in the variable called "results" and then append it to your list "results_list"

Try the following:

```
results_list = []

for i in range (1,21):
    url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=XX&primary_release_date.gte=2000-01-01&with_genres=35&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=" + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url, timeout = 10)
    #each page is a dictionary. we get only "results" which is a list.
    #so each iteration of the loop gives us a list to work with
    results = response.json()['results']
    results_list.append(results)
    final_list.extend(results_list)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Failed to get data:', response.status_code)
print(results_list)
```